# Checkbox - check add text, uncheck remove original text in text area

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function moveNumbers(num) { 
   var txt=document.getElementById("result").value; 
   txt=txt + num; 
   document.getElementById("result").value=txt; 
} 
</script>

<textarea id="result" name="image_id" rows="8" cols="11" readonly>

</textarea>
<tr>

    <?php
        $path = "photos/";
        $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder");
        echo "<table height='500px'width='800px'align='center'border='1'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {

          if($file == "index.php")
          continue;
          if($file == ".")
          continue;
          if($file == "..")
          continue;

          echo ($x % 6 == 0) ? "</tr><tr>" : "";
          echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='add' value='$file'             
          onclick='moveNumbers(this.value)'>
          <img src='photos/$file'alt='$file' style='height:auto;width:50%;'alt='$file'>
          <br>
          $file
          </td>";
          $x++;
       }
       echo "</tr>";
       echo "</table>";
       closedir($dir_handle);
   ?>
```

Hi all, having some trouble with the check boxes. Click on the check box, text appears in text area no problem. I have been trying to figure out how to when you uncheck the check box the text is removed. E.G. Checked -> Text 123 inputted, Uncheck -> Test 123 removed.
Cheers.

Comment: upon unchecking, set document.getElementById("result").value=default_txt; where default_txt is the default text in the result.

Comment: Thanks for you help Muhammed but dosen't seem to work? Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the above... Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want different activity depending on whether your text box is being checked or unchecked. At the moment, you call one method whenever you click on the checkbox, so now you need to look at the state of the checkbox, when it is clicked on. Give your checkbox an ID, and swap out your Javascript for this.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function moveNumbers(num) { 
 if(document.getElementById("checkBoxId").checked){
  var txt=document.getElementById("result").value; 
  txt=txt + num; 
  document.getElementById("result").value=txt; 
 }
 else{
 document.getElementById("result").value=txt="";
 }
} 

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, works fine on first photo listed with check box but others wont add text unless the first one has been ticked first?

Comment: I found the issue, I can't do it this way as the check boxes will need ID's.. the PHP finds image files adds check boxes next to all displayed images..

Comment: In that case, take a look at the [event.currentTarget](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_currenttarget.asp) property. (Sorry this reply took a while!)

Answer (score -1):

just add jquery and this will help you..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>        
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textCheck').change(function(){
        if($('#textCheck').attr('checked'))
        {
            $('#myTextArea').val($('#textinput').val());
        }
        else
        {
            $('#myTextArea').val('');
        }
    });
});
</script>
<input type = "text" name = 'textinput' id = 'textinput' />
<textarea name = 'myTextArea' id = 'myTextArea'></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" name='textChck' id='textCheck' />
```